# I have an svg I have to move the green bulge like a slider button on the svg path. Any Correct way to do it?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, css-animations

Here is the svg. It's a slider with the green bulge at the top of it.
I have to move the green bulge like a slider button on the svg path and as it moves ahead the slider should turn green.That slider should move when we scroll down the page. It should be on scroll.
I know that I can calculate the stroke length and gap length and can change the stroke-dasharray property. But still not getting it to do in a perfect way.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="57" height="820" viewBox="0 0 57 820" fill="none">
    <path d="M14 812C14 813.105 14.8954 814 16 814C17.1045 814 18 813.105 18 812L14 812ZM14 -8.74228e-08L14 812L18 812L18 8.74228e-08L14 -8.74228e-08Z" fill="#E8E8E8"/>
    <path d="M36 812H16" stroke="#E8E8E8" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <path d="M14 104C14 105.105 14.8954 106 16 106C17.1046 106 18 105.105 18 104L14 104ZM14 -8.74228e-08L14 104L18 104L18 8.74228e-08L14 -8.74228e-08Z" fill="#3DCD58"/>
    <g filter="url(#filter0_d_6_14)">
        <path d="M15.2627 91.1843L16 91L16.7373 91.1843C17.5428 91.3857 18.2289 91.912 18.6321 92.6378L22.0631 98.8136C24.1837 102.631 24.0635 107.298 21.7492 111.001L18.8813 115.59C18.333 116.467 17.3716 117 16.3373 117H15.6627C14.6284 117 13.667 116.467 13.1187 115.59L10.2508 111.001C7.93651 107.298 7.81629 102.631 9.9369 98.8136L13.3679 92.6378C13.7711 91.912 14.4572 91.3857 15.2627 91.1843Z" fill="#3DCD58"/>
    </g>
    <path d="M46.7656 819.984H40.6406C39.0729 819.984 37.8333 819.492 36.9219 818.508C35.8646 817.414 35.3724 816.01 35.4453 814.297C35.4818 813.932 35.6641 813.75 35.9922 813.75C36.2474 813.75 36.5755 813.641 36.9766 813.422C37.5234 813.13 37.7969 812.656 37.7969 812C37.7969 811.38 37.5052 810.888 36.9219 810.523C36.5208 810.305 36.1927 810.195 35.9375 810.195C35.6094 810.159 35.4453 809.958 35.4453 809.594C35.4453 807.807 35.9557 806.422 36.9766 805.438C37.9974 804.453 39.2188 803.979 40.6406 804.016H46.7656C46.9115 804.016 47.0391 804.089 47.1484 804.234C47.2943 804.344 47.3672 804.471 47.3672 804.617V806.969H54.5859C55.1328 806.969 55.5885 807.151 55.9531 807.516C56.3177 807.88 56.5 808.372 56.5 808.992C56.5 809.576 56.3177 810.049 55.9531 810.414C55.5885 810.742 55.1328 810.906 54.5859 810.906H47.0391C46.8932 810.906 46.7656 810.852 46.6562 810.742C46.5469 810.596 46.4922 810.451 46.4922 810.305C46.4922 810.122 46.5469 809.977 46.6562 809.867C46.7656 809.758 46.8932 809.703 47.0391 809.703H54.5859H54.6406C54.8594 809.703 55.0234 809.648 55.1328 809.539C55.2786 809.393 55.3516 809.193 55.3516 808.938C55.3516 808.609 55.2422 808.391 55.0234 808.281C54.9141 808.208 54.7682 808.172 54.5859 808.172H46.7656C46.5833 808.172 46.4375 808.117 46.3281 808.008C46.2188 807.898 46.1641 807.753 46.1641 807.57V805.219H40.6406H40.5859C39.4557 805.219 38.526 805.583 37.7969 806.312C37.1042 806.969 36.7214 807.917 36.6484 809.156C36.9401 809.229 37.2318 809.357 37.5234 809.539C38.4714 810.086 38.9453 810.906 38.9453 812C38.9453 812.62 38.7995 813.148 38.5078 813.586C38.2526 813.951 37.9062 814.242 37.4688 814.461C37.2135 814.607 36.9401 814.716 36.6484 814.789C36.7214 816.029 37.0859 817.013 37.7422 817.742C38.4349 818.435 39.401 818.781 40.6406 818.781H46.1641V816.43C46.1641 816.284 46.2188 816.156 46.3281 816.047C46.4375 815.901 46.5833 815.828 46.7656 815.828H54.4766H54.5312C54.8229 815.865 55.0417 815.792 55.1875 815.609C55.2969 815.5 55.3516 815.336 55.3516 815.117C55.3516 814.862 55.2969 814.661 55.1875 814.516C55.0417 814.37 54.8411 814.297 54.5859 814.297H47.0391C46.8932 814.297 46.7656 814.242 46.6562 814.133C46.5469 814.023 46.4922 813.896 46.4922 813.75C46.4922 813.568 46.5469 813.422 46.6562 813.312C46.7656 813.203 46.8932 813.148 47.0391 813.148H54.5859C55.1693 813.148 55.6432 813.331 56.0078 813.695C56.3724 814.023 56.5547 814.497 56.5547 815.117C56.5547 815.664 56.3724 816.12 56.0078 816.484C55.6068 816.849 55.0964 817.031 54.4766 817.031H47.3125V819.383C47.3125 819.529 47.2578 819.674 47.1484 819.82C47.0391 819.93 46.9115 819.984 46.7656 819.984Z" fill="#E8E8E8"/>
    <defs>
        <filter id="filter0_d_6_14" x="0.426758" y="83" width="31.1465" height="42" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
            <feOffset/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4"/>
            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.239216 0 0 0 0 0.803922 0 0 0 0 0.345098 0 0 0 1 0"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_6_14"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_6_14" result="shape"/>
         </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Any one has any Idea. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Learn to drag SVG elements: https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/

Comment: Please show us the relevant JS that you have tried already. Also, please clarify - do you want the 'blob' to move just on scroll or on drag as well?